# multiplayer flash quiz AS2

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, multiplayer

Im making a flash web based quiz with AS 2..
Im using Adobe flash cs3, sql database, and PHP to make a connection..
But for the question and the answer choice im using XML which i generate it from the sql database..

The game rules is like Who wants to be a Billionaire..
I have done with Single mode game..
Here's the problem, i must develop it so we can play with Multiplayer mode..
Where can handle 2 or more player whose got the same question and they can compare their score with other at the end of the game.

Honestly im so blind with that Multiplayer things..
I have download many tutorial and free templates for multiplayer game, but all of that is so difficult to understand, and many of them use AS3..

Please help, or give me some idea with this multiplayer things..
Sorry for my grammar anywy, thx..

Comment: if you "have done with Single mode game", as start point you can try to identify in the game flow how you can include different users in a same session and then begin handling their scores in a individual way while you keep sharing the same session, I think it does not depend of if you use AS2 or AS3, but  about your logic

Answer (score 0):

well, even though it would be much easier to work with as3 in this case, as it can read both binary socket and xml socket, there are some solutions to as2.

since you never worked with this stuff, you definitely want a central server for communication, rather than trying to hack your way through trying to make a p2p game. there already have been implemented a handfull of multiplayer apis.

and there's a few available multiplayer apis that support as2 that i know of, check them out:

- [nonoba multiplayer api](http://www.nonoba.com/developers/documentation/multiplayerapi/)
- [smartfox server](http://www.smartfoxserver.com/)

if you run a search like [this](http://www.google.com/search?q=as2%20smartfox) or [this](http://www.google.com/search?q=as2%20nonoba) you get not only the API/documentation but also a plenty of tutorials as well.

well, have fun exploring!